# What is the name of Salesforce database application?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I want to use Salesforce DB and Airbyte.
First step is to configure connection to Salseforce.
It's needed to provide Client ID and Client Secret.
Following official guide:
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000DLgbQAG
I found out that I need to know the name of my application which have both of Client ID and Client Secret.

I went to App Manager at Salesforce and have seen a lot of applications, but I could not determine which application linked to Salesforce database.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your own "connected app" for this specific integration purpose where you decide the name and what you allow the app to do on user's behalf (the oauth scopes), which websites are allowed to use it (which callback URLs are allowed)... In that sense all connected apps you see in there already potentially can connect to database - depends if they have API access scope.

"App" created in any org can be used to connect to any org (imagine making a mobile application - you'd want just 1 set of client I'd and secret to maintain, not separate keys for every org your app would be connecting to). But if you create it in sandbox and later delete /refresh the sandbox - the app will be destroyed and the keys useless.